# is there any possibility that J2ME application can be signed illegally?

Tags: java-me, certificate

I found a site [J2ME certifier](http://simak.ru/javacert/)
which certifies J2ME application. I am curious to know if there is any possibility to sign J2ME application without buying them from verisign or thawte. How that site certifies J2ME application?

Answer (score 0):

No, J2ME applications cannot be signed illegally.

That website offers a service for people to install a certificate to their own phones, then sign an application with that certificate, so that the application doesn't ask for permission all the time.

So if you install those certificates, it may be possible to fool a phone that the application is signed.